# Ngrx store value not displaying in component template

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx-store

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ngrx, and after reading through the documentation I've tried to throw together a quick example using them.

My problem is that although the store is set up and the reducers are working as expected (I can see the store updating in redux tools), templates won't show anything.

I've checked similar questions but I can't seem to get it working.

Any help is appreciated!

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CounterExampleComponent } from './counter-example/counter-example.component';
import * as ScoreboardReducer from './store/counter.reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CounterExampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot( { game: ScoreboardReducer.counterReducer } ),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument( {
      maxAge: 25
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**counter.reducer.ts**

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as CounterActions from './counter.actions';


export interface State {
    home: number,
    away: number
}

export const initialState: State = {
    home: 0,
    away: 0
}

const _counterReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on( CounterActions.homeIncrement, ( state ) => ( { ...state, home: state.home + 1 } ) ),
    on( CounterActions.awayIncrement, ( state ) => ( { ...state, away: state.away + 1 } ) ),
    on( CounterActions.homeDecrement, ( state ) => ( { ...state, home: state.home - 1 } ) ),
    on( CounterActions.awayDecrement, ( state ) => ( { ...state, away: state.away - 1 } ) ),
    on( CounterActions.reset, ( state ) => ( { ...state, home: 0, away: 0 } ) ),
);

export function counterReducer( state: State | undefined, action: Action ) {
    return _counterReducer( state, action );
}
```

**counter-example.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as CounterActions from '../store/counter.actions';
import { State } from '../store/counter.reducer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-counter-example',
  templateUrl: './counter-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter-example.component.scss']
})
export class CounterExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  homeCount$: Observable<number>;
  awayCount$: Observable<number>

  constructor( private store: Store<State>) {
    this.homeCount$ = this.store.select( store => store.home );
    this.awayCount$ = this.store.select( store => store.away );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  home_increment() {
    this.store.dispatch( CounterActions.homeIncrement() );
  }

  home_decrement() {
    this.store.dispatch( CounterActions.homeDecrement() );
  }

  away_increment() {
    this.store.dispatch( CounterActions.awayIncrement() );
  }

  away_decrement() {
    this.store.dispatch( CounterActions.awayDecrement() );
  }

  reset() {
    this.store.dispatch( CounterActions.reset() );
  }

}
```

**counter-example.component.html**

```
<div>
    <button (click)="home_increment()">Increment</button>

    <div>Home Count: {{ homeCount$ | async }}</div>

    <button (click)="home_decrement()">Decrement</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button (click)="away_increment()">Increment</button>

    <div>Away Count: {{ awayCount$ | async }}</div>

    <button (click)="away_decrement()">Decrement</button>
</div>
<br>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset Counter</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is near identical to the example [on the ngrx store website](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) but I tested it and it does not display the home or away on the `component` for me either.

The `StoreModule.forRoot` is looking for an `ActionReducerMap` so I got it working by changing a couple of things in the code.

**counter.reducer.ts**
uses a `CounterState` that is added to an App wide state `AppState`. The reducers are then exported ready for `app.module.ts`

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  counter: counterReducer
};

export interface AppState {
  counter: CounterState
}

export interface CounterState {
  home: number,
  away: number
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { reducers } from './store/counter.reducer';

StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {})
```

**counter-example.component.ts**
slight change to `selectors`

```
import { AppState } from './store/counter.reducer';

constructor( private store: Store<AppState>) {
  this.homeCount$ = this.store.select( store => store.counter.home );
  this.awayCount$ = this.store.select( store => store.counter.away );
}
```